# deserializing integer array as object array with json.net

Tags: json, json.net

I'm using this class as the base class for my enumerations: 
[link](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes/)
I created a custom json.net converter to handle the enumerations when serializing/deserializing my objects. Serialization works fine, but 
when I try to deserialize an object which has a enumeration collection property, json.net throws a SerializationException with the following message:

Unexpected end when deserializing array. Path '', line 11, position 2.

UPDATE : Here are all my classes with a cutdown version of the Enumeration class.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var employee = new Employee
        {
            Name="asd",
            Types = new List<EmployeeType>()
            {
                EmployeeType.AssistantToTheRegionalManager,
                EmployeeType.Manager,
                EmployeeType.Servant
            }
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee, new EnumerationTypeConverter());
        var deserializedEmployee=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(json,new EnumerationTypeConverter());
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeType> Types { get; set; }
}


public class EmployeeType : Enumeration
{
    public static readonly EmployeeType Manager
        = new EmployeeType(0, "Manager");
    public static readonly EmployeeType Servant
        = new EmployeeType(1, "Servant");
    public static readonly EmployeeType AssistantToTheRegionalManager
        = new EmployeeType(2, "Assistant to the Regional Manager");

    public EmployeeType() { }
    private EmployeeType(int value, string displayName) : base(value, displayName) { }
}

public class EnumerationTypeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue((value as Enumeration).Value);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        int? value = reader.ReadAsInt32();
        return value.HasValue ? Enumeration.FromValue(value.Value, objectType) : null;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Enumeration));
    }

}
public abstract class Enumeration
{
    public int Value
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    protected Enumeration(int value, string displayName)
    {
        Value = value;
        DisplayName = displayName;
    }        

    public static IEnumerable<Enumeration> GetAll(Type type)
    {
        var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        foreach (var fieldInfo in fields)
        {
            yield return fieldInfo.GetValue(null) as Enumeration;
        }
    }

    public static object FromValue(int value, Type type)
    {
        return GetAll(type).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Value == value);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JsonReader.ReadAsInt32()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_ReadAsInt32.htm) reads the *next* JSON token from the stream.  You want the value of the *current* token.  So do:

```
var value = (int?)JToken.Load(reader);
```